# jQuery function not work in blogger

Tags: jquery

I using a jQuery plugin - [blocksit](https://github.com/kennyooi/blocksit) to create a PInterest like image album.
But it not work after i place the code to blogger, but work in JSBin.

Firebug show:

> TypeError: $(...).BlocksIt is not a function
>     $('#BIcontainer').BlocksIt({

I try to put the css and javascript between  tag,

and read another SOF post said replace all "$" to "jQuery" but also occur same error.

Here is the JSBin demo:
http://jsbin.com/joweqilume/1/

And it is my blogger page:
http://justpmp.blogspot.hk/p/pmp-useful-articles-list.html

Comment: try jq=$.noConflict();   function before javascript you used

Comment: Are you sure that you included the plugin library to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you have 2 instances of jQuery linked in the same page:

- v1.7.1 (line 1021)
- v1.8.4 (line 1269)

Remove either one to resolve the issues. Not recommend to use `.noConflict()` in double installation environment.